# MongoDB Persistence via EclipseLink NoSql JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final

Tags: persistence, eclipselink, jboss7.x, mongodb-java

I am trying to use EclipseLink NoSql Persistence for MongoDB in JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final.

I am trying to use the EntityManager like:

```
    EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mongo")
            .createEntityManager();

    Model m = new Model();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(m);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="mongo" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.Model</class>
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="dorop-and=create=tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database"
                value="org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoPlatform" />
            <property name="eclipselink.nosql.connection-spec"
                value="org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoConnectionSpec" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I added the EclipseLink module to my JBoss install using the instructions specified [here](http://mpashworth.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/configuring-eclipselink-2-3-1-in-jboss-7-1/). I also added javax.resource.jar as a dependency in the EclipseLink modules.xml and created a JBoss module for javax.resource. **If there is any way to avoid having to add the module to JBoss, and instead put it in my war, then please let me know.**

Here is the current problems I am facing, which is weird because I know it is loading the javax.resource.jar (I got a different error before without it) and the missing javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory class is in there.

```
1:35,286 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/barebones].[com.Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet com.Servlet threw exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/resource/cci/ConnectionFactory
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:602) [eclipselink-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:186) [eclipselink-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:278) [eclipselink-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:304) [eclipselink-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:282) [eclipselink-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
    at com.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:22) [classes:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/resource/cci/ConnectionFactory
    at org.eclipse.persistence.eis.EISConnectionSpec.connectToDataSource(EISConnectionSpec.java:146) [eclipselink-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoConnectionSpec.connectToDataSource(MongoConnectionSpec.java:150) [org.eclipse.persistence.nosql_2.4.0.v20120608-r11652.jar:]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.eis.EISLogin.connectToDatasource(EISLogin.java:73) [eclipselink-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connectInternal(DatasourceAccessor.java:330) [eclipselink-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connect(DatasourceAccessor.java:418) [eclipselink-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ConnectionPool.buildConnection(ConnectionPool.java:216) [eclipselink-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ConnectionPool.startUp(ConnectionPool.java:504) [eclipselink-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.connect(ServerSession.java:484) [eclipselink-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.login(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:734) [eclipselink-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:215) [eclipselink-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:542) [eclipselink-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.cci.ConnectionFactory from [Module "org.eclipse.persistence:main" from local module loader @2b76e552 (roots: /usr/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules)]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Recently added <provider> to persistence.xml and added eclipselink.jar to JBoss modules - roadblock updated.

Comment: The error is because the ResourceException class cannot be found when loading a class.  This is because EclipseLink is trying to load the "MongoPlatform" class using the application classloader and then is getting an exception when using it to create a new instance.  Unfortunately the missing ResourceException class means the actual exception cannot be thrown.  Try making sure the javax.resource is added as an EclipseLink module dependency

Comment: @Chris - Man... I did that last week but I botched the modules.xml for  javax/resource. Updated roadblock and added step. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issuse.
Please add  "< module name="javax.resource.api" />"
to the dependencies in the module.xml of org.eclipse.persistence.

It worked for me.